# How to bind TipTap to parent v-model in Vue 3 script setup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, rich-text-editor, tiptap

I'm trying to use `tiptap` as a child component and pass its content to the parent's `v-model` but tiptap's [documentation](https://tiptap.dev/installation/vue3) only seems to provide info on how to do this without `script setup`, which uses a different API.

This is my `parent` component:

```
<template>
    <cms-custom-editor v-model:modelValue="state.content"/>
    <p>{{state.content}}</p>
</template>


<script setup>
import CmsCustomEditor from '../../components/backend/cms-custom-editor.vue'
import {reactive} from "vue";

const state = reactive({
    content: '<p>A Vue.js wrapper component for tiptap to use <code>v-model</code>.</p>',
})

</script>
```

and this the `child` component with `tiptap`:

```
<template>
  <div id="cms-custom-editor" class="cms-custom-editor">
    <editor-content :editor="editor"/>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import {useEditor, EditorContent} from '@tiptap/vue-3'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'

const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    content: props.modelValue,
    onUpdate: () => {
        emit('update:modelValue', editor.getHTML())
    }
})
</script>
```

As soon as I type something into the editor field, this code line fails:

```
emit('update:modelValue', editor.getHTML())
```

and throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: editor.getHTML is not a function
    at Editor2.onUpdate (cms-custom-editor.vue?t=1654253729389:28:42)
    at chunk-RCTGLYYN.js?v=89d16c61:11965:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Editor2.emit (chunk-RCTGLYYN.js?v=89d16c61:11965:17)
    at Editor2.dispatchTransaction (chunk-RCTGLYYN.js?v=89d16c61:12252:10)
    at EditorView.dispatch (chunk-RCTGLYYN.js?v=89d16c61:9138:27)
    at readDOMChange (chunk-RCTGLYYN.js?v=89d16c61:8813:8)
    at DOMObserver.handleDOMChange (chunk-RCTGLYYN.js?v=89d16c61:8924:77)
    at DOMObserver.flush (chunk-RCTGLYYN.js?v=89d16c61:8575:12)
    at DOMObserver.observer (chunk-RCTGLYYN.js?v=89d16c61:8455:14)
```

I've used the approach from the docs (chapter 5. v-model), which like I said, is not designed for `script setup`.

Answer (score 12):

Man, the docs are confusing. They mix up standard `composition api` and `script setup`. Anyway this is how it works:

```
const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    content: props.modelValue,
    onUpdate: ({editor}) => {
        emit('update:modelValue', editor.getHTML())
    }
})
```

Comment: emit not working for script setup vue 3 on my case. Need more details of this answer.

Comment: @HonestKnight in case you still need it: You probably have to define emit like: 
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

Comment: @HonestKnight what `user2466601` said.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
<script setup>
import { useEditor, EditorContent } from '@tiptap/vue-3'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'
import { onBeforeUnmount, watchEffect } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
});

const emits = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

watchEffect(() => props.modelValue, (newValue, oldValue) => {
    const isSame = newValue === oldValue;
    if (isSame) {
        return;
    }

    editor.value?.commands.setContent(newValue, false)
});

const editor = useEditor({
    content: props.modelValue,
    extensions: [
        StarterKit,
    ],
    onUpdate: ({ editor }) => {
        let content = editor.getHTML()
        emits('update:modelValue', content)
    },
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    editor.destroy();
})

</script>
```